# Createjs Drag and drop - drop target isn't registering

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, createjs

I'm attempting to do a drag and drop. I cant seem to register a drop when I release the circle over the rectangle. How do I fix the issue? My target is always null no matter where I drop it on the stage or over the rectangle.

```
var rectangle = new createjs.Container();
        rect = new createjs.Shape();
        rect.graphics.beginFill("blue").drawRect(50, 50, 250, 210);
        rect.name = "rectangle";
        rect.x = 300;
        rect.y = 300;
        rectangle.addChild(rect);
        stage.addChild(rectangle);

        circle = new createjs.Shape();
        circle.name = "mycircle";
        circle.graphics.beginFill("red").drawCircle(15, 15, 15);
        circle.x = 15;
        circle.y = 80;


        var dragger = new createjs.Container();

        dragger.addChild(circle);
        dragger.name = "dragger1";
        stage.addChild(dragger);

        dragger.on("pressmove", function (evt) {
            evt.currentTarget.x = evt.stageX;
            evt.currentTarget.y = evt.stageY;
            stage.update();
        });

        dragger.on("pressup", function (evt) {
            var target = dragger.getObjectUnderPoint(evt.rawX, evt.rawY, 0);
            console.log("this is my target");
            console.log(target);

        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `dragger.getObjectUnderPoint()`, which will return an object within `dragger` that is under the point. I'm guessing you want it to return `rect`, which is not in `dragger`. Just run `stage.getObjectUnderPoint()` instead.

Note of course, that if your dragged object is under the point when you do the check, it will be returned instead. There are lots of ways to work around that but its a separate topic.

http://jsfiddle.net/gskinner/by3humee/

Comment: Thanks! that really helped